# пошаговая отладка в PyCharm

Tags: отладка, pycharm

Как запустить пошаговый отладчик? Он вроде как встроенный, но при запуске Debugger, он просто запускает код, и нет пошаговости. Нет вывода значения переменных именно в этот момент выполнения кода.

Answer (score 3):

Поставьте точку останова на том месте, откуда хотите вести отладку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть есть такой код:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = 1.2
c = 11
d = input()
print(a, b, c, d)
```

Когда вы пошагово дойдете до строки с вводом и выполните её, то у вас должна появится возможность ввести значение в вкладке `Console`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня проблема в том, что при отладке программы я не могу ничего ввести. по ходу программы пользователь вводит данные, я же в процессе отладки ничего не могу ввести

Comment: @allay, при пошаговом выполнении код с вводом игнорируется?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю в какой ОС Вы работаете, но, к сожалению, с отладкой в PyCharm есть ряд особенностей.

При пошаговом выполнении в *nix системах (в частности, я говорю про Ubuntu 16.04, но думаю, что подобные фокусы есть и в других операционках) возникает проблема с горяими клавишами. Проблема заключается в том, что невозможно использовать их на любой другой раскладке, кроме `EN`. Среда не реагирует. Связано это с тем, что в списке горячих клавиш (`File -> Settings` необходимо выбрать раздел `Keymap`) отсутствуют русские комбинации клавиш.

[image: Keymap]

Эту проблему можно решить, если найти соответствующие команды (например, Run...) и добавить соответствующие русские комбинации:

[image: Run...]

[image: Русские комбинации клавиш]

Такая же ситуация наблюдается и со средой IntelliJ Idea.

Под Windows проблема аналогичная. Но здесь, плюс к этому добавляется неработоспособность команды `Step Into`. При попытке войти в функцию вываливается ошибка с непонятными логами в виде цифр и букв в непонятных последовательностях. Аналогичная проблема возникает при попытке перейти на следующую строку на условных операторах, но это происходит не всегда. Случаи, когда такое случается, а когда нет, мной выявлены не были. Обойти это недоразуменее можно команду `Resume Program`, т.е. выполнить до точки останова. Таким образом, можно допрыгнуть до нужного места в коде, в т.ч. внутри функции. Но от такого рода отладки часто устаёшь. Поэтому призываю поставить виртуалку, либо непосредственно *nix систему.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отображать значения переменных в коде - в настройках debug поставьте галочку Show Valuse Inline.

[image: Debug PyCharm]

Answer (score 0):

Если ещё актуально. Красной меткой надо отмечать все места которые ты намерен обработать отладчиком. Вот смотри, отметил и нажал на отладчик, жми на кнопку следующего шага, засветится консоль где надо ввести занчения, ввёл, засветится отладчик, сигнализирующий о продолжении работы программы согласно инструкциям, с учётом введённого материала.[image: Отметка всех шагов которые надо отладить]
[[image: подсветка того что консоль ожидает введения данных][2]]